# How does this class implement the "__iter__" method without implementing "next"?

Tags: python, iterator, yield

I have the following code in django.template:

```
class Template(object):
    def __init__(self, template_string, origin=None, name='<Unknown Template>'):
        try:
            template_string = smart_unicode(template_string)
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            raise TemplateEncodingError("Templates can only be constructed from unicode or UTF-8 strings.")
        if settings.TEMPLATE_DEBUG and origin is None:
            origin = StringOrigin(template_string)
        self.nodelist = compile_string(template_string, origin)
        self.name = name

    def __iter__(self):
        for node in self.nodelist:
            for subnode in node:
                yield subnode

    def render(self, context):
        "Display stage -- can be called many times"
        return self.nodelist.render(context)
```

The part I am confused about is below.  How does this `__iter__` method work?  I can't find any corresponding `next` method.

```
def __iter__(self):
        for node in self.nodelist:
            for subnode in node:
                yield subnode
```

This is the only way that I know how to implement `__iter__`:

```
class a(object):
    def __init__(self,x=10):
        self.x = x
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next(self):
        if self.x > 0:
            self.x-=1
            return self.x
        else:
            raise StopIteration
 ainst = a()
 for item in aisnt:
     print item
```

In your answers, try to use code examples rather than text, because my English is not very good.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#generator-types):

> If a container object’s `__iter__()`
>   method is implemented as a generator,
>   it will automatically return an
>   iterator object (technically, a
>   generator object) supplying the
>   `__iter__()` and `__next__()` methods.

Here is your provided example using a generator:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, x=10):
        self.x = x
    def __iter__(self):
        for i in reversed(range(self.x)):
            yield i

a = A()
for item in a:
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 16):

That `__iter__`method returns a python **generator** (see the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generators)), as it uses the `yield` keyword.
The generator will provide the next() method automatically; quoting the documentation:

> What makes generators so compact is that the __iter__() and next() methods are created 
>   automatically.

*EDIT:*

Generators are really useful. If you are not familiar with them, I suggest you readup on them, and play around with some test code.

Here is some more info on iterators and generators from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/can-somebody-explain-me-the-python-yield-statement).

Comment: Is it meant to be called by client code?  I assumed not since it has the __fname__ form

Comment: the --fname-- form where those dashes are underscores

Comment: I have no idea about Django, but in the end it's just python syntax. When a iterator needs to be created for a Template object, its  `__iter__(self)` hook will be called. It will then return a Generator object which has the correct next() method.

Comment: Right - so is there any other way that you're supposed to call it besides using for/in?

Comment: "it" in this case being `__iter__`, as I am currently under the impression that any function beginning with `__` is not meant to be called

Comment: @danben: You don't call `obj.__iter__()`, you call `iter(obj)`.  `iter(obj)` will translate into a call to `obj.__iter__()` if it is defined, much like `Foo()` will translate into a call to `Foo.__init__()` if it is defined.

Comment: methods/member variables of the form `__x__` usually have a special meaning in python (e.g. `__dict__` and `__builtin__`). The `__iter__` method of an object is called when trying to iterate over the object, such as in a `for .. in ..:` loop.