# What's the advantage of using yield in __iter__()?

Tags: python, generator, yield

What is the advantage of using an generator(`yield`) inside an `__iter__()` function? After reading through *Python Cookbook* I understand "If you want a generator to expose extra state to the user, don’t forget that you can easily
implement it as a class, putting the generator function code in the `__iter__()` method."

```
import io

class playyield:
    def __init__(self,fp):
        self.completefp = fp

    def __iter__(self):
        for line in self.completefp:
            if 'python' in line:
                yield line

if __name__ =='__main__':
    with io.open(r'K:\Data\somefile.txt','r') as fp:
        playyieldobj = playyield(fp)
        for i in playyieldobj:
            print I
```

**Questions**:

1. What does extra state means here?
2. What is the advantage of using `yield` inside `__iter__ ()` instead of using a separate function for `yield`?

Comment: Because now `playyield` is *iterable*, but you didn't have to write an *iterator* class, since now `playyied.__iter__` returns a generator, which is an iterator. It is quite convenient.

Comment: Your question is not providing entire context. The quote you mentioned from the Python Cookbook is with respect to the problem `**Problem:** You would like to define a generator function, but it involves extra state that you would like to expose to the user somehow`. The _extra state_ here implies other information related to other parts of your program.

Comment: I also recommend to check this [blog post](http://nvie.com/posts/iterators-vs-generators/)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Without generator functions, you would have to implement something like this, if you want to follow best practices:

```
In [7]: class IterableContainer:
   ...:     def __init__(self, data=(1,2,3,4,5)):
   ...:         self.data = data
   ...:     def __iter__(self):
   ...:         return IterableContainerIterator(self.data)
   ...:

In [8]: class IterableContainerIterator:
   ...:     def __init__(self, data):
   ...:         self.data = data
   ...:         self._pos = 0
   ...:     def __iter__(self):
   ...:         return self
   ...:     def __next__(self):
   ...:         try:
   ...:              item = self.data[self._pos]
   ...:         except IndexError:
   ...:             raise StopIteration
   ...:         self._pos += 1
   ...:         return item
   ...:

In [9]: container = IterableContainer()

In [10]: for x in container:
    ...:     print(x)
    ...:
1
2
3
4
5
```

Of course, the above example is contrived, but hopefully you get the point. With generators, this can simply be:

```
In [11]: class IterableContainer:
    ...:     def __init__(self, data=(1,2,3,4,5)):
    ...:         self.data = data
    ...:     def __iter__(self):
    ...:         for x in self.data:
    ...:             yield x
    ...:
    ...:

In [12]: list(IterableContainer())
Out[12]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

As for state, well, it's exactly that - objects can have state, e.g. attributes. You can manipulate that state at runtime. You *could* do something like the following, although, I would say it is highly inadvisable:

```
In [19]: class IterableContainerIterator:
    ...:     def __init__(self, data):
    ...:         self.data = data
    ...:         self._pos = 0
    ...:     def __iter__(self):
    ...:         return self
    ...:     def __next__(self):
    ...:         try:
    ...:              item = self.data[self._pos]
    ...:         except IndexError:
    ...:             raise StopIteration
    ...:         self._pos += 1
    ...:         return item
    ...:     def rewind(self):
    ...:         self._pos = min(0, self._pos - 1)
    ...:

In [20]: class IterableContainer:
    ...:     def __init__(self, data=(1,2,3,4,5)):
    ...:         self.data = data
    ...:     def __iter__(self):
    ...:         return IterableContainerIterator(self.data)
    ...:

In [21]: container = IterableContainer()

In [22]: it = iter(container)

In [23]: next(it)
Out[23]: 1

In [24]: next(it)
Out[24]: 2

In [25]: it.rewind()

In [26]: next(it)
Out[26]: 1

In [27]: next(it)
Out[27]: 2

In [28]: next(it)
Out[28]: 3

In [29]: next(it)
Out[29]: 4

In [30]: next(it)
Out[30]: 5

In [31]: it.rewind()

In [32]: next(it)
Out[32]: 1
```

Comment: Over a year old, but why not just include `__next__` in the `IterableContainer` class? Simply set `def __iter__(self): return self` with the `__next__` as part of the class you wish to iterate, and now its an iterable is it not?

Comment: @pstatix because that turns it into an *iterator*. All *iterators* are *iterable*, but not all *iterables* are *iterators*. Ideally, you should separate the two. For example, iterators should be *single pass*, but generally, you want to be able to iterate over most containers multiple times.

Comment: I suppose where I'm lost on semantics is that the generator automatically provides the `__next__`, so while not explicitly defined as part of the class, a generator is still an iterator, so it would reason using the generator or an `__iter__` and `__next__` combination makes the class an iterator either way.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1960330/6741482) speaks to what I am getting at, are we just talking best practices here for separation of concerns? As I take it, a generator is an iterator, so picking either method is really based upon how you want to use the class. But I do see that as a generator, its iterable only once a time, whereas implementing as an iterator allows more maneuvers.

Comment: @pstatix separation of concerns is a plus. A *generator object* is an iterator. A generator function *returns a generator object*. So, since the container's `__iter__` returns an iterator, it is now an iterable. But we don't want the *container* to be an *iterator* and implement `__next__`. I'm not sure what you mean by "more maneuvers".

Comment: @pstatix so just ask yourself this, why do none of the built-in containers implement `__next__`? (or choose a container from your favorite library, e.g. `numpy` or `pandas`)

Comment: Okay, I can understand wanting the container not to be an iterator. By "more maneuvers" I meant implementations like your `rewind()` method and such. As for the built-ins, I have no idea, enlighten me?

Comment: @pstatix because *containers should be iterable, but they shouldn't be iterators*, because you want to be able to iterate over them many times, and you want to be able to make multiple iterators from one container.