# Generators as iterator member functions

Tags: python, iterator

So I understand that sometimes instead of defining **iter** and **next** methods within a class that is supposed to be iterable, using just an **iter** method containing a yield statement suffices. Actually why? Just do avoid boilerplate code?

However, I dont get why the following snippet yields three iterations

```
class BoundedRepeater:
    def __init__(self, value, max_repeats):
        self.value = value
        self.max_repeats = max_repeats
        self.count = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.count >= self.max_repeats:
            raise StopIteration
        self.count += 1
        return self.value
```

if called like this

```
for item in BoundedRepeater("Hello", 3):
    print(item)
```

but if I change the methods to

class BoundedRepeater:
    def **init**(self, value, max_repeats):
        self.value = value
        self.max_repeats = max_repeats
        self.count = 0

```
class BoundedRepeater:
    def __init__(self, value, max_repeats):
        self.value = value
        self.max_repeats = max_repeats
        self.count = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        if self.count >= self.max_repeats:
            raise StopIteration
        self.count += 1
        yield self.value
```

I only get one iteration instead of three

Comment: The 2nd code should have a loop: `for _ in range(self.max_repeats): yield self.value`.  [What's the advantage of using yield in __iter__()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45685538/whats-the-advantage-of-using-yield-in-iter)

Answer (score 2):

The second example gives you only one iteration because the `yield` statement is called only once, because `__iter__` is called only once.  The `__iter__` method does not return the next value (and therefore is not called once per value), it returns an iterator that has all the values.

You could write

```
class SmallPrimes:
    def __iter__(self):
        yield 2
        yield 3
        yield 5
        yield 7
```

which shows that one single call to `iter` contains all the values.

In your case, the `BoundedRepeater` class would put the `yield` in a `for`-loop:

```
class BoundedRepeater:
    def __init__(self, value, max_repeats):
        self.value = value
        self.max_repeats = max_repeats

    def __iter__(self):
        for _ in range(self.max_repeats):
            yield self.value
```

The execution of `__iter__` is paused during each yield, and then resumes when the next value is required.  During that pause, all the context is kept.  Note how there is no need to keep track of a counting variable (`self.count` in your first example).

For your specific example, which is about repeating a value V a number N of times, you do not need to write your own class.  You can just write a function:

```
def bounded_repeat(V, N):
    for _ in range(N):
        yield V

for v in bounded_repeat(V, N):
    y = do_something(v)
```

But you do not need to write that function because it already exists:

```
import itertools
for v in itertools.repeat(V, N):
    y = do_something(v)
```

However, unless V is heavy and N is huge, just stick to some good old Python:

```
for v in [V] * N:
    y = do_something(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generator function, but you should yield results in a loop, in your case bounded by the number `max_repeat`

I think your `__iter__` method should be written as follow:

```
    def __iter__(self):
        for i in range(self.max_repeats):
            yield self.value
        return
```

I tried and it generates as many items as specified in max_occurences.

```
br = BoundedRepeater('tagada', 5)
for item in br:
    print(item)

# ->tagada
# ->tagada
# ->tagada
# ->tagada
# ->tagada
```

Comment: thank you guys. My question aimed more at the low-level details in the way that I wonder why there is no need for an internal loop in the next method of the first implementation, whereas I do need one in the second version. I still have trouble wrapping my head around that.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, iter is only called once if the iterable is used e.g. in the for loop. But next of the first implementation is called until the exception is raised. All hidden in the loop syntax. For the yield version with the correct loop syntax, control is temporarily passed back to the call-site after iter was called once and only once. However, upon the next loop iteration, control is given back to the __iter__ method, even without being called explicitly, to yield the next value. Did I get that right?