# How to transform a generator function into an iterator object in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, generator

Often generator functions are simpler to write than iterators, e.g. consider this example generator function

```
def generator_fn():
    x = 0
    for y in range(10):
         x += y
         yield x
```

Is there a straightforward way to transform an arbitrary generator function into an iterator object, i.e.,

```
class IteratorFromGenerator(object):

    def __init__(self, generator_fn):
        self.generator_fn = generator_fn

    def __iter__(self):
        # ???
        pass

    def __next__(self):
        # ???
        pass
```

To me this seems favorable but impossible.
Favorable, because generator functions are often simpler to write and require less code. Usually, I begin writing generator functions and at some point, I need an iterator object (e.g. when `generator_fn` is a member of my `class Foo` and I want to write `for x in my_foo` instead of `for x in my_foo.generator_fn()`.
Impossible, because generator functions define the execution flow of the loop process, while iterator objects simply offer their `__next__` interface to be requested by an undefined "outer" execution flow.

Am I right or is there a possibility to do this?

Of course, apart from the trivial, memory-consuming solution of consuming all generated elements into a list.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can get an iterator from a generator with the [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) function, if an iterator is actually what you want.

Comment: built in function `iter` should do exactly this

Comment: @khelwood thanks, but how exactly, simply returning `iter(generator_fn())` in `__iter__` seems not to work

Comment: This question doesn't make a lot of sense. What are you actually trying to accomplish? Generator objects (which is what is returned from a generator object) **are already iterators**. Using `iter` on them is pointless, it just returns the exact same generator object (since all well-defined iterators should simply return `self` from `__iter__`)

Comment: If you are trying to make a class *iterable*, then just define a `__iter__` with `return self.generator_method()`

Comment: Read this answer I wrote to a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45685692/5014455

Comment: Yes, thanks and sorry, I was wrong, it just seemed not to work due to a subtle implementation problem of my algorithm, which brought me to this question ;)

Comment: Just to be clear, an IteratorFromGenerator class doesn't make sense. "Impossible, because generator functions define the execution flow of the loop process, while iterator objects simply offer their `__next__` interface to be requested by an undefined "outer" execution flow." Is totally wrong. Again, *generator functions return generator objects which **are iterators*** that is, generator objects provide a `__iter__` method (which simply returns itself as all iterators should) and a `__next__` method. Generator functions *are convenient ways of writing iterators*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, that is exactly what I was missing, I didn't know the underlying mechanics and wrongly identified generator functions and generator objects.

Answer (score 0):

A function with yield is a function that, when called, returns an instance of a generator object (which is a specific type of iterator).
So, as already mentioned in the comments, you only have to do:

```
def generator_fn():
    x = 0
    for y in range(10):
         x += y
         yield x

iterator_from_generator_fn = generator_fn()
```

However, by doing this, you will probably encounter this problem: [Resetting generator object in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271320/resetting-generator-object-in-python), because by definition, you can only iterate over a generator once.

What you probably want is  an iterable : an object which `__iter__` method returns an iterator object. Something like this :

```
class IterableFromGenerator(object):

    def __init__(self, generator_fn):
        self.generator_fn = generator_fn

    def __iter__(self):
        return generator_fn()


iterable_from_generator_fn = IterableFromGenerator(generator_fn)
```